# How do I left align text in bootstrap and react

Tags: html, css, reactjs, twitter-bootstrap, react-bootstrap

I am using react, react-bootstrap.

This is my react code snippet:

```
<Navbar bg="light" expand="lg" className="d-lg-none container-fluid">
   <Navbar.Toggle aria-controls="responsive-course-nav" /> 
   <span className="d-sm-inline-block">Test 123</span>
   { // ... rest of the components }
</Navbar>
```

This is my snippet converted to HTML when rendered to browser:

```
<nav class="d-lg-none container-fluid navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light"><button
        aria-controls="responsive-course-nav" type="button" aria-label="Toggle navigation"
        class="navbar-toggler collapsed"><span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span></button>
    <div class="d-flex text-right">Test 123</div>
    <div class="navbar-collapse collapse" id="responsive-course-nav">
        <div class="mr-auto navbar-nav">
            <div class="nav-item dropdown" style="padding-left: 0em; padding-right: 0.5em;"><a aria-haspopup="true"
                    aria-expanded="false" id="basic-nav-dropdown" href="#" class="dropdown-toggle nav-link"
                    role="button"><span class="d-lg-none" style="font-size: 21px;"> Course Content </span></a></div>
            <div class="nav-item dropdown" style="padding-left: 0em; padding-right: 0.5em;"><a aria-haspopup="true"
                    aria-expanded="false" id="basic-nav-dropdown" href="#" class="dropdown-toggle nav-link"
                    role="button"><span class="d-lg-none" style="font-size: 21px;"> Course Content </span></a></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

It gets rendered as follows:

[image]

I want "Test 123" to be left aligned just after the hamburger menu button. How do I set CSS styles or bootstrap classes?

**Demo**

[codesandbox demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/rough-breeze-bw3f71?file=/src/App.js:446-497)

**Update:**

Here is my corresponding CSS from dev tools if it helps:

[image]

**PS:**

My `package.json`:

```
"react": "^17.0.1"
"bootstrap": "^4.6.0",
"react-bootstrap": "^1.4.3"
```

Comment: `<div class="d-flex text-right">Test 123</div>` `text-right` doesn't tells you anything ?

Comment: "Doesnt tell" means? It gives me output as shown in an image.

Comment: @Ernesto added snapshot of CSS from rendered page's Chrome dev tools. Might help debugging.

Comment: Add style={{ marginRight: "auto" }} inside your span tag

Answer (score 0):

Add me-auto class.

```
<span className="me-auto d-sm-inline-block">Test 123</span>
```

Add padding as needed eg:- px-3

```
<span className="me-auto px-3 d-sm-inline-block">Test 123</span>
```

Code Sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/dawn-sunset-gib5x5?file=/src/App.js:365-424

For your version of bootstrap use the below classes.
Bootstrap: 4.6.0

```
 <span className="mr-auto pl-4 ">Test 123</span>
```

Code Sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/cocky-bhabha-vmlhqj?file=/src/App.js

Comment: Change to my bootstrap and react-bootstrap version and it will fail: https://codesandbox.io/s/relaxed-rgb-ywlyyh

Comment: @Rnj I have updated the answer to work with your version. Please check

Comment: Can you please explain how it is achieving the desired result. I understand you are setting left padding to 4 with `pl-4`. What is meaning of `mr-auto` - setting right margin to auto? What does it mean by setting it to `auto`? Noob in CSS ... :\

Comment: yes ```mr-auto``` is 'margin-right : auto' it basically means that the element will give up all the available space on the right side. So in scenarios where you have align an element in the center you can use ```margin-right: auto; margin-left: auto;``` meaning that the element will give up equal space on both sides. Hope this helps :)